# Is it possible to make hist3 plots smoother?

Tags: matlab

I use hist3() function to plot the density of points. It creates a grid and finds the number of points in each grid, then it creates the plot. But the colors on the plot are discrete.
Is there an option to make this distribution smooth, i.e. make transition from one color to another smoother. Now all the cells of the grid have different colors, from grin to yellow and the distribution is not apparent.

I use the following code.

```
axis equal;
colormap(jet);
n = hist3(final',[40,40]);
n1 = n'; 
n1( size(n,1) + 1 ,size(n,2) + 1 ) = 0; 
xb = linspace(min(final(:,1)),max(final(:,1)),size(n,1)+1);
yb = linspace(min(final(:,2)),max(final(:,2)),size(n,1)+1);
pcolor(xb,yb,n1);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check out the [`colormap()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html).

Comment: I use summer colormap. I also tried other colormaps, but it didn't help. I just don't want to see those gird-lines, but want to get a smooth transition from one cell to another.

Comment: Use [interp2](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) to create an interpolated surface from the histogram, then display it.

Comment: I just added the code I use. Could you please thell me how to use that function in this case?

Comment: I discovered Python's `matplotlib` does smoothing by default of images shown by `imshow`. If you're willing to try it, it's very much worth it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to use the `gridfit` function from the [matlab file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998-surface-fitting-using-gridfit). The smooth effect comes from both the interpolation (more points to plot) and the full use of the available color (`colormap jet` here). Note that `edgecolor` is set to `none`so that the black lines are removed.

As it is used here, it takes the output of hist3 (20x20 matrix) and interpolate it (100x100). It then plot a surface using `surf`. In addition, you can uncomment the `camlight` option.

```
final = randn(1000,2)';  
n = hist3(final',[20,20]); %binning  
figure('Color','w');  

%your code with pcolor   
subplot(1,2,1);  
axis equal;  
colormap(jet);  
n1 = n';   
n1( size(n,1) + 1 ,size(n,2) + 1 ) = 0;   
xb = linspace(min(final(:,1)),max(final(:,1)),size(n,1)+1);  
yb = linspace(min(final(:,2)),max(final(:,2)),size(n,1)+1);  
pcolor(xb,yb,n1)  


%density with gridfit function  
subplot(1,2,2);  
nb_interp_point = 100;
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:size(n,1),1:size(n,2));  
zgrid = gridfit(x(:), y(:), n, nb_interp_point, nb_interp_point);  
surf(zgrid,'EdgeColor','none')  
set(gca,'YDir','reverse');  
view(-90,90);  
% camlight right  
% lighting phong
```

Here is the result

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 3):

To get rid of the gridlines use the following:

```
hchild=get(gca,'children');
set(hchild,'edgecolor','none')
```

Colormaps are m x 3 (rgb) arrays. You are free to create your own `colormap`. For instance you can narrow the range of the `colormap` you are using, as in the following example:

```
cmap=colormap(summer);
range = [40:64]; % <-- here I am using a 64 element colorspace 
                 %  and narrowing the selection to the upper range
nc = size(cmap,1);

range = [range(1):(range(end)-range(1))/(nc-1):range(end)];
cmap(:,1)=interp1([1:nc],cmap(:,1),range);
cmap(:,2)=interp1([1:nc],cmap(:,2),range);
cmap(:,3)=interp1([1:nc],cmap(:,3),range);
colormap(cmap)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't make this code work. Could you please check it?

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really useful! p.s. I just deleted those brackets, because they were not necessary.

Comment: Glad to help... (and I like brackets!)